# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when converting Objective-C code to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I try to use a Objective-C framework to my project and have some questions when converting Objective-C code to Swift.

One of the APIs:

```
- (void)ioFrameChannel:(PTChannel*)channel didReceiveFrameOfType:(uint32_t)type tag:(uint32_t)tag payload:(PTData*)payload
```

*payload.data* is a struct like this:

```
typedef struct _PTExampleTextFrame {
  uint32_t length;
  uint8_t utftext[0];
} PTExampleTextFrame;
```

I want to get `PTExampleTextFrame.utftext` which is a message send from the framework

So, I create a local `struct`:

```
struct CPTExampleTextFrame {
    var length: UInt32
    var utf8text: UnsafePointer<UInt8>
}
```

And write like this:

```
var textFrame = UnsafePointer<CPTExampleTextFrame>(payload.data).memory
textFrame.length = CFSwapInt32(textFrame.length)
print(textFrame.length) // textFrame.length is correct!
let message = NSString(bytes: textFrame.utf8text, length: Int(textFrame.length), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) // error
print(message)
```

> But I get an error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x31)

Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

And also I give you the framework's example which is in Objective-C:

```
- (void)ioFrameChannel:(PTChannel*)channel didReceiveFrameOfType:(uint32_t)type tag:(uint32_t)tag payload:(PTData*)payload {
  if (type == PTExampleFrameTypeTextMessage) {
    PTExampleTextFrame *textFrame = (PTExampleTextFrame*)payload.data;
    textFrame->length = ntohl(textFrame->length);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:textFrame->utf8text length:textFrame->length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self appendOutputMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]: %@", channel.userInfo, message]];
  } else if (type == PTExampleFrameTypePing && peerChannel_) {
    [peerChannel_ sendFrameOfType:PTExampleFrameTypePong tag:tag withPayload:nil callback:nil];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, I'd really recommend that you keep code that interfaces with C as Objective-C code. Interfacing C and Swift directly is an absolute pain.

And an array of char and an unsafe mutable pointer to char are obviously not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Finally, I used an Objective-C method to build the message I need and that just takes me one minute... So, I think, in some situations, Swift is not always the best choice in a Swift Project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a local struct, it's memory layout is not compatible with c type.

After clarification:

`let x: PTExampleTextFrame = UnsafeMutablePointer<PTExampleTextFrame>(payload.data).memory`

And use x as you will

Comment: I tried before and I got an error `Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<()>') to specified type 'PTExampleTextFrame' (aka '_PTExampleTextFrame')`. After that I use the local struct

Comment: How does payload.data definition look like?

Comment: Updated my answer in that case

Comment: When I press cmd+r, I get an error 'Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11', what does this mean?